# Assign a variable from grep

Tags: shell, grep

I'm trying to assign a variable with a value I get from grep, here's my code

```
a="i 
am
a
string
"
b="$a"|grep am
echo "$b"
```

I expect the result is `am`, but the result `b` is empty.  But when I code `echo "$a"|grep am` directly, I get the right result. why and how can I assign the result to b?

Comment: `b=$(echo "$a" | grep am)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:-

**`b=$(echo "$a"|grep am)`
**